Images Not Displaying in Output When Running Program with Repeater
<asp:Repeater ID="d1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="last">
            <a href="#"><img src="../admin/images/<%#Eval("product_images") %>" alt="" /></a>
            <div class="product-info">
                <h3><%#Eval("product_name") %></h3>
                <div class="product-desc">
                    <h4>Available Qty:<%#Eval("product_qty") %></h4>
                    <p><%#Eval("product_desc") %></p>
                    <strong class="price"><%#Eval("product_price") %></strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

-----------shop.aspx.cs-----------

public partial class shop : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\projc3\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from product";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        d1.DataSource = dt;
        d1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}

I tried like everything that I could do even I tried chatgpt but didnt work aswell.. so I have two folder name project and admin and I want and I am creating product gallery using repeater in C# but from admin panel my uploaded images are saved in images folder in the admin folder ..and I have to display image in project folder I am getting everything like name, description, price quantity except the image of it I would be glad to be helped.
here its like that my actual images are located in d:/admin/images

And what is the data source or how are you feeding data to the repeater? So, share the code that fills out and sends data to the repeater.

@AlbertD.Kallal i just edited it i am still confuse about how its still not working

@PatelDhruv Do you actually need to use a Repeater instead of a <% for() %> loop?

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); <--A SELECT * FROM Product SQL command is a query - so you're using the wrong method here.

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); <-- You don't need a SqlDataAdapter - use a SqlDataReader instead.

@Dai i did as you said still all data loaded but expect images

Your relative-path .../admin/images/etc is probably wrong. Use a ~/ (application-root-relative URI with ResolveUrl()).

@Dai yep i tried that too and i checked in browser but still not showing the image i tried checking error using console and it showed this error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

@Dai also i think repeater trying to get data from admin/images/images why is it taking images two times i think we resolve that problem it should work but i dont really know how to troubleshoot it
from projc3/admin but my images are stored in seprate folder in name admin and admin folder is not under the projc3 folder

@PatelDhruv May I ask why you're using WebForms at all in 2024?

@Dai i am college student and thats what they are teaching us so we have to do whatever they instruct us
